# How to get references(where the field is used) of a custom field in salesforce via API or Tooling API

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, metadata, tooling-api, field-dependencies

I want to find the references of a custom field i.e. where is the field used e.g. Layouts, Apex Classes, etc. via the AP/Tooling API.

There is an option on UI in professional salesforce orgs called **Where is this used**
[image]

I want to access the same data but via the APIs

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get dependency on any custom object using MetadataComponentDependency tooling API. But, this is still in beta version ([MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm)).

```
v49.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,+MetadataComponentId,+MetadataComponentNamespace,+MetadataComponentName,+MetadataComponentType,+RefMetadataComponentId,+RefMetadataComponentNamespace,+RefMetadataComponentName,+RefMetadataComponentType+FROM+MetadataComponentDependency
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this programmatically is to use the NPM package sfdc-soup (https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/sfdc-soup) which enhances the capabilities (and fixes many of the bugs) of the dependency API